# Could not reference button in my custom collection view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Um using Collection Views and I've made my own  custom view cell and linked it to it's own xib file.

In cellForItemAtIndexPath method when I create the cell, I could reference to some labels and text fields in the cell but I face the problem which I couldn't reference to the some other buttons (to change them fonts or to add target to them )

I don't know what is the reason but when I try to NSLog the values of `myButton.titleLabel.text` it always print null.

```
    NSMutableArray *data = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:cv.tag];
    NaaiCell *cell = (NaaiCell *)[_naaiCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier
                                                                                forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Naai* cellData = (Naai*)[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //these values works fine for me and I can reference to them.

    [cell.naaiId setText:cellData.naaiId];
    cell.name.font = font;
    [cell.name setText:[c convertArabic:cellData.deceasedName]];

    [cell.text setText:[c convertArabic:cellData.text]];
    cell.text.font = sFont ;
    cell.text.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    [cell.text setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];


    //the problem with these three buttons.

    cell.btnAazi.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Droid Arabic Kufi" size:10];
    cell.btnMushatra.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Droid Arabic Kufi" size:10];
    cell.btnBarkyah.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Droid Arabic Kufi" size:10];


    [cell.btnAazi addTarget:self action:@selector(azziOnTheFly:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    genericCell = cell;
```

Comment: Does a log of cell.btnAazi return your button, or nil? Also note that the titleLabel property is nil for system buttons. Are you using a system button?

Comment: Update on my last comment -- the docs say that the titleLabel property is nil for system buttons, but when I tested it, that was not the case. I was able to set the font of a button with the code you have (but using systemFontOfSize: to change the font).

Comment: @rdelmar um using custom buttons not system buttons,and when I log cell.btnAazi it returns nil not the button.
Even I've the same code with TableViewCell and it worked fine with me!

Comment: It sounds like you never connected the outlets. Did you check that?

Comment: nop I've connected the outlets, and to make sure I've deleted them and connected them again and I face the same issue, It's only for buttons not with labels not with textfields not with any thing else,

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see how that's possible. If you can post your project somewhere, I'll take a look at it, but it seems like you've done everything correctly, so I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Ok, I'll send it to you

Comment: Do you need my email, or is it visible on my profile?

Comment: I need your mail :)
I was just asking you :)

Comment: It's rdelmar@comcast.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a debugging time by @rdelmar, he finally reached to that: even though I connected the outlets by dragging it to .h file, but when I went to XIB file then -> show the connection inspector tap I found that the outlets did't connected !!!
I connected them and every thing worked great :)
thanks @rdelmar for your time again :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In you xib file for the custom cell, make sure the values for the cell reuse identifier are the same as what you are specifying in this code:

```
NaaiCell *cell = (NaaiCell *)[_naaiCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier
                                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I would guess that is is somehow using a standard collection view cell.

Comment: No, he is not using a standard cell -- he said in his question that he can reference some of the custom properties of his cell, just not the buttons, so this is not the problem.

Comment: exactly like @rdelmar said!
um referencing to some values already so um on the right place bro